# Commit failed with error: pathspec did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

Не могу сделать коммит в Android Studio.Не так давно все работало хорошо. Единственное что изменял название репозитория, кроме этого никаких изменений не было. 
Вот Event Log с ошибкой:

```
Commit failed with error
            0 files committed, 10 files failed to commit: changed database scheme
            pathspec 'src/main/java/com/example/jeka/exampledrawerbar/fragments/FragmentCurrentWeather.java' did not match any file(s) known to git.
            error: pathspec 'src/main/java/com/example/jeka/exampledrawerbar/services/UpdateService.java' did not match any file(s) known to git.
            error: pathspec 'src/main/java/com/example/jeka/exampledrawerbar/activities/WeatherMainActivity.java' did not match any file(s) known to git.
            error: pathspec 'src/main/java/com/example/jeka/exampledrawerbar/fragments/FragmentWeatherMain.java' did not match any file(s) known to git.
            error: pathspec 'src/main/java/com/example/jeka/exampledrawerbar/model/WeatherItem.java' did not match any file(s) known to git.
            error: pathspec 'src/main/java/com/example/jeka/exampledrawerbar/fragments/QueryPreferenceFragment.java' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Comment: `изменял название репозитория` – что вы имеете в виду? Папку с проектом переименовали?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, нет репозиторий на hithub переименовал, не уверен что это стало причиной ошибки но мало ли

Comment: Это требует только поменять адрес репозитоиря локально (`git remote set-url origin git@github/new-name...`) и может сломать только pull/push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio делает коммиты весьма необычным образом:

```
git -c core.quotepath=false commit --only -F <message.txt> -- <files>
```

- `<message.txt>` — это длинный путь к файлу, из которого нужно взять сообщение коммита. Наверное, так удобнее.
- `-- <files>` — список файлов, из которых будет сделан коммит. Вне зависимости о того, что вы сами руками добавили (`git add`) в индекс, будут использованы только эти файлы, потому что есть параметр `--only`.

  Судя по сообщению:

  > error: pathspec ... did not match any file(s) known to git

  в этом списке есть файлы, которых на диске нет. Возможно, путь неправильный. Или AS помнит старый путь, который был до переименования.

Попробуйте сделать коммит руками, должно получиться.

Comment: "Попробуйте сделать коммит руками", не через студию а через терминал?

Comment: @UjinUkr ага, я имел в виду терминал. )

Comment: @UjinUkr ну как, получилось?

Comment: еще не заливал но коммит делает.Спасибо